# jQuery Get Label By Text

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, label, selector

I have a simple problem in which I created some ugly code for.

My problem is require to get a label by the text that it displays e.g:

```
    <div class="editor-label">
    <label for="iwantthisid">Test<span class="editor-label-required">*                </span>

    </label>
```

So here I would like to search the page(as quick as possible) to get the label with text = "Test".

I would then like to pull the "For" value from that label.

What is the best way to do this.

I know to solve the for part its just `$(element).attr("for")` its the first step I am stuck at!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$('label').filter(function () {
    return this.firstChild.nodeValue.trim() === 'string';
}).attr('for');
```

[Simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/VxfTe/).

As noted, for more assurance of (if precise casing isn't required, and to provide for those browsers that don't implement `String.trim()`):

```
$('label').filter(function () {
    return $.trim(this.firstChild.nodeValue).toLowerCase() === 'string';
}).attr('for');
```

[Simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/VxfTe/1/).

To use this approach in a functional context:

```
function getLabelByText(needle, caseSensitive) {
    var str;
    return $('label').filter(function(){
        str = $.trim(this.firstChild.nodeValue);
        return caseSensitive ? str === needle : str.toLowerCase() === needle.toLowerCase();
    });
}

console.log(getLabelByText('Test',false));
```

[Simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/VxfTe/2/).

These various approaches are dependent upon the text you're searching for being the *`firstChild`* of the `label` elements, though (basing that decision upon the current HTML you've provided in your question).

Comment: How would i call that function with a parameter?

Comment: Aside from `trim()`ing the string, you might find it helpful to convert it `toLowerCase()` in some cases.

Answer (score 3):

Use this

```
$('label:contains(Test)').attr('for')
```

Comment: Thanks, would you say this is the most optimal way of searching?

Comment: @LmC - definitely not, but it works, and you'll probably never notice the performance hit.

Comment: Of course, this will also match `Test Test` and `I have a Test`, which may be an issue. [`:contains` doesn't offer exact matching, only substring matching](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/).

Comment: @Blazemonger - and the label also contains `*        ` so that's probably not an issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Just assign an id to the label like this:

```
<label id="theLabel" for="iwantthisid">Test<span class="editor-label-required">*</label>
```

and get the values via `$("#theLabel").attr("for")`

Comment: The whole reason for searching for the text is because ID's are out with our control.